# How to share image in Android using Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-extension

I want to share an image located in assets folder using 'Kotlin'.How can I achieve that Similar block of code in android :

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
intent.setType("image/jpeg");
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Share Image"));
```

Comment: When you use the Java-to-Kotlin converter in Android Studio, what do you get? Note that Android itself has no ability to share an asset directly -- you either need your own `ContentProvider`, a third-party provider like [my `StreamProvider`](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-provider), or copy the asset to a file and then use `FileProvider`.

Comment: @CommonsWare any example could be helpful

Comment: Example code for *what*?

Comment: What you consider "Android" code up there, is actually just Java code written using Android framework components (Intent, Activity, etc.). Are you asking us to help you convert the exact code above to Kotlin, or to help you with any approach in Kotlin achieving something similar? If it is the first case, you need to expand what `Intent.createChooser` does for you.

Answer (score 6):

First you need to have the data stored somewhere. If you are compiling against API 24 or above, the **FileProvider** is a popular choice:

Declare the provider in your `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
<application>
  <!-- make sure within the application tag, otherwise app will crash with XmlResourceParser errors -->
  <provider
    android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
    android:authorities="com.codepath.fileprovider"
    android:exported="false"
    android:grantUriPermissions="true">
      <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/fileprovider" />
  </provider>
</application>
```

Next, create a resource directory called `xml` and create a `fileprovider.xml`. Assuming you wish to grant access to the application's specific external storage directory, which requires requesting no additional permissions, you can declare this line as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths>
    <external-files-path
        name="images"
        path="Pictures" />

    <!--Uncomment below to share the entire application specific directory -->
    <!--<external-path name="all_dirs" path="."/>-->
</paths>
```

Finally, you will convert the File object into a content provider using the FileProvider class:

```
// getExternalFilesDir() + "/Pictures" should match the declaration in fileprovider.xml paths
val file = File(getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), "share_image_" + System.currentTimeMillis() + ".png")

// wrap File object into a content provider. NOTE: authority here should match authority in manifest declaration
val bmpUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(MyActivity.this, "com.codepath.fileprovider", file)
```

[Source](https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Sharing-Content-with-Intents#sharing-files-with-api-24-or-higher)

Now you have a way to store and retrieve `Uri` for an individual File. The next step is to simply create an intent and start it by writing the following:

```
val intent = Intent().apply {
        this.action = Intent.ACTION_SEND
        this.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, bmpUri)
        this.type = "image/jpeg"
    }
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, resources.getText(R.string.send_to)))
```

*Notice the `bmpUri` is the value you retrieved just before.*

[Source](https://developer.android.com/training/sharing/send.html#send-binary-content)

You should remember to consider Runtime permissions if you are running API 23 or above. Here's a good tutorial on [that](https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Managing-Runtime-Permissions-with-PermissionsDispatcher).